# Saving Object With Relation Parse.com not PFUser CurrentUser

Tags: ios, object, parse-platform

I'm working with Parse.com ... My app relies heavily on relations between users and to use this thing PFRelation that creates a relationship between the User and the User corrent selected ...

Whenever the Current User chooses User " A" creates the relationship with PFRelation and User "A" receives a push notification where it is informed that the current user has started to follow him.

Now I have created through a label , even the badge number that should appear not to CurrentUser but the USER "A" that receives the notification . The badge I'm talking about is NOT the classic Icon badge but it is a badge that appears on NavigationBar .

To do all this I should try to save an entry in the special class _USER CurrentUser but not to the USER "A" .. Could you tell me how could I do? I already have an array fetches the names of users and displays them in tablebiew .

For example, to create the relationship with the user selected on the Tableview I implemented a PFUser connected with the array

```
- (void) tableView : ( UITableView * ) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath : ( NSIndexPath * ) indexPath {
[ self.TableView deselectRowAtIndexPath : indexPath animated : NO] ;
    
if (! isFiltered ) {

    UITableViewCell * cell = [ self.TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath : indexPath ] ;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark ;

    PFUser * user = [ self.Utenti objectAtIndex : indexPath.row ] ;
    PFRelation * Report = [ [ PFUser currentUser ] relationforKey : @ "Relationship "] ;
    PFInstallation currentInstallation * = [ PFInstallation currentInstallation ] ;
    NSString * RegistraNomeUtente = [ NSString stringWithFormat : @ "% @ " , [user objectForKey : FF_USER_NOMECOGNOME ]] ;
 
.....
```

Comment: Can you use join table that has `from_user` & `to_user` entities. So that you can query specific user how follow current user or count total users who is following the current one.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply ... I've heard of this method but I have not figured out how I should do sincerely ... There 'some tutorials or specific discussion where he explains exactly what to do?? I'm new to parse.com ... What is a Join table .. Excuse my bad english, I'm Italian

Comment: Pls see my answer, I'm not good at English as well, so don't worry :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you create a new class on parse named such as `Activity`. From this class, you will have `from_user` attribute is a pointer to `User` class and `to_user` is also a pointer to `User` class. Maybe you can have one more attribute name `type` used to indicate what type of relationship betweens users. Each user can "follow", "post comment", "like" each other.

Now get back to your code. I assume that you will have a particular `PFUser` object when you click on a specific row of your tableView. In `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you save new `Activity` object by using the following pseudo code:

```
PFObject *activityObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Activity"];
[activityObj setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"from_user"];
[activityObj setObject:OtherUserObj forKey:@"to_user"];
[activityObj setObject:@"follow" forKey:@"type"];
[activityObj saveInBackGround];
```

Now you have a relationship between current user and other user. You can get total number of following user to display in your badge item by:

```
PFQuery *activityQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
[activityQuery whereKey:@"from_user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
[activityQuery whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"follow"]];
[activityQuery countObjectsInBackground];
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much, tomorrow morning I try the code and let you know how it worked: D

The badge for now I do not need to show the total number of follow but to tell the user that there is' a new news (in this case the new friendship): D do you think you could do this by playing with the query?

Comment: you're welcome! I think you can do it by push notification when a new `activityObj` has been saved successfully :)

Comment: But talk about the push Notification of Parse? those entering the badge not only the icon in the App navigationbar ... Hope I'm wrong: D

Comment: I don't quite understand your concern. But if you use push notification, your `user A` will be notified immediately on real time. Other way around is you can update your badge periodically using timer (refresh your data from Parse) to notice user that he has a new user following them.

Comment: No no no worries: D ehheh I was just saying that a badge on the nav bar I know that you can 'do only creating a UIView because the push notification it only adds to the Icon App: D Anyway tomorrow I try everything and I inform you immediately about how went the project: D

Thank you so much you have been very kind: D